# How a web site recognize the web browser?

Tags: web, browser

Some sites are arrange the layout by itself when accessed through a smartphone or a pc. I wonder how is it done (Javascript? getting the browser data?). I would really appreciate some help, I am learning JAVA, thanks.

Comment: Usually using Javascripts.. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

Answer (score 0):

Each request of web browser have agent-string, which contain necessary information. Look at this page for description of agent string. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

Answer (score 0):

The browser sends a header with each GET request with a variety of information about itself. See [here](http://pgl.yoyo.org/http/browser-headers.php) for an example, but the particular information your are talking about (browser type) is sent in the `User-Agent` field. With some http client libraries, you are able to control some of the fields sent in order to assume the identity of other types of client.

Answer (score 0):

This is done by reading the user agent, usually using javascript (on websites).

Javascript example [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html).

Answer (score 0):

The Website recognizes the Browser via the user agent string.  This is a unique identifier that tells the site the browser type and version.

This can be detected in javascript via `navigator.userAgent` 
It is also sent to the server in the [Get Request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GET_request#Request_methods) as a header field

**Example:**

> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5

The **Java Servlet code** to get this would be ([More Info Here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/servlets/request_headers.shtml)):

```java
public final void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
  String agent = req.getHeader("user-agent");
  if (agent != null && agent.indexOf("MSIE") > -1) {
    // Internet Explorer mode
  } else {
    // Non-Internet Explorer mode
  }
}
```

**Obligatory Wikipedia Reference:**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

> The User-Agent string format is currently specified by Section 14.43
>   of RFC 2616 (HTTP/1.1) The format of the User-Agent string in HTTP is
>   a list of product tokens (keywords) with optional comments. For
>   example if your product were called WikiBrowser, your user agent
>   string might be WikiBrowser/1.0 Gecko/1.0. The "most important"
>   product component is listed first. The parts of this string are as
>   follows:
>
> Product name and version (WikiBrowser/1.0) Layout engine and
>   version(Gecko/1.0). In this case, this indicates the Layout engine and
>   version. Unfortunately, during the browser wars, many web servers were
>   configured to only send web pages that required advanced features to
>   clients that were identified as some version of Mozilla.
>
> For this reason, most Web browsers use a User-Agent value as follows:
>   Mozilla/[version] ([system and browser information]) [platform]
>   ([platform details]) [extensions]. For example, Safari on the iPad has
>   used the following:
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us)
>   AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405 The components
>   of this string are as follows:
>
> Mozilla/5.0: Previously used to indicate compatibility with the
>   Mozilla rendering engine (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us):
>   Details of the system in which the browser is running
>   AppleWebKit/531.21.10: The platform the browser uses (KHTML, like
>   Gecko): Browser platform details Mobile/7B405: This is used by the
>   browser to indicate specific enhancements that are available directly
>   in the browser or through third parties. An example of this is
>   Microsoft Live Meeting which registers an extension so that the Live
>   Meeting service knows if the software is already installed, which
>   means it can provide a streamlined experience to joining meetings.